# fopen and open produce files with different file permissions

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, unix

These two code snippets produce files with different file-permissions. Example 1 creates the expected default file-permissions but Example 2 does not. What's the explanation for this?

OS: Mac OS X version: 10.6.4

Xcode version: 3.2.2, 64 bit

---

```
// Example 1
FILE *fh1 = fopen("Test1.txt", "w+x");

if (fh1) {
    fwrite("TEST1", 1, 5, fh1);
    fclose(fh1);
}
```

Creates:
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff    5 29 Jul 00:41 Test1.txt

```
// Example 2
int fh2 = open("Test2.txt", O_EXCL | O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);

if (fh2 >= 0) {
    write(fh2, "TEST2", 5);
    close(fh2);
}
```

Creates:
----------  1 me  staff    5 29 Jul 00:41 Test2.txt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `O_CREAT` you need to add a third argument to `open`, the mode. For instance:

```
int fh2 = open("Test2.txt",
               O_EXCL | O_CREAT | O_WRONLY,
               S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH);
```

This would be equivalent to 0666. Be aware that this mode is then masked by the process's umask, meaning the permissions you specify will usually be reduced a bit. A typical umask is 0022, which would result in a mode of 0666 & ~0222 = 0644, i.e. `-rw-r--r--`.

From **man open**:

> The *oflag* argument may indicate that the file is to be created if it does not exist (by specifying the `O_CREAT` flag).  In this case, open requires a third argument `mode_t mode`; the file is created with mode *mode* as described in `chmod(2)` and modified by the process' umask value (see `umask(2)`).

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. I don't know how I missed that since I scoured over the docs a dozen times. Now I don't have to use the 'fchmod' kludge.

Answer (score 2):

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

The argument **mode** specifies the permissions to use in case a new file is created. See http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl2_open.htm

In your case, you'll want to set **mode** with value `0644`